# Trying to alternate background color for odd and even <li>, but javascript is making all even

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css, html-lists

I would like to alternate background colors for odd and even list items in my unordered list. This worked great until I added javascript inside of each list item. If I remove the javascript, the background color alternates as it should. With the javascript, I can see in firebug that each list item looks like it is even.

The reason why I need to have the javascript inside of each list item is because I am dynamically displaying each list item from the database, and assigning classes based upon the application id ($apid).

My css to alternate background color of list items:

```
ul.version li:nth-child(odd) {
background: #EEE;
}

ul.version li:nth-child(even) {
background: #FFF;
}
```

And the applicable code in my php page:

```
<ul class="version">

                                <li class="versionheader">

                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="appname">
                                            Application
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="appvidlink">
                                            Video
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="appwish">
                                            Wishlist
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="appimplement">
                                            Implemented
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>



                                </li>



                            <?php
                            //get child applications
                            $application_id_result = mysql_query("SELECT apid from products_app_categories WHERE cid = '$catid'");
                                while($application_id_row = mysql_fetch_array($application_id_result)) {

                                    $apid = $application_id_row['apid'];



                            //see if user already has app in their wishlist
                            $application_wished_result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(apid) FROM products_wishlist_users WHERE apid = '$apid' AND uid = '$uid'");
                                while($application_wished_row = mysql_fetch_array($application_wished_result)) {




                                    if($application_wished_row['COUNT(apid)'] < 1) {

                                        $appwished = false;
                                    } else {
                                        $appwished = true;
                                    }



                            $application_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE child = '1' AND parent_id = '$pid' AND id = '$apid'");
                                while($application_row = mysql_fetch_array($application_result)) {

                                    $apname = $application_row['name'];

                                    ?>


                                    <li class="app app_<?php echo $apid; ?> <?php if($appwished) { echo 'appwished'; } ?>">

                                        <ul>
                                            <li class="appname">
                                                <?php echo $apname; ?>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="appvidlink">
                                                [video]
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="appwish">
                                                <?php if(!$appwished) {
                                                    echo '<a class="btn addtowishlist addtowishlist_' . $apid . '">Add</a>';
                                                } else {
                                                    echo '<span class="checkmark"></span>';
                                                } ?>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="appimplement">
                                                <?php if(!$implemented) {
                                                    echo '<a class="btn addtoimplemented">Yes</a>';
                                                } else {
                                                    echo '<span class="checkmark"></span>';
                                                } ?>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>



                                    </li>



                                    <script type="text/javascript">

                                        $('.addtowishlist_<?php echo $apid; ?>').click(function(){

                                            $.get("wishlist/wishlistupdate.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&apid=<?php echo $apid; ?>");

                                            $("#wishlistapps").load("wishlist/wishlistdisplay.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>");


                                            $("li.app_<?php echo $apid; ?>").addClass("appwished");

                                            return false;
                                        });


                                    </script>





                                <?php   
                                } } }?>

                        </ul>
```

Comment: Please provide rendered HTML, preferably a live example, rather than tag soup.

Comment: oy. mixing three languages in one source file... no wonder you are having problems.

Comment: I know this isn't what you're asking for, but if you use the LESS css framework, you can color your list items however you want and not have to do this really ugly mix of business and presentation logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set background color with javascript at end of the script.

```
$('ul.version li:even').css('background-color','#EEE');
$('ul.version li:odd').css('background-color','#FFF');
```

make sure to load jquery in header :x

Comment: I have to wait three minutes to accept the answer...but it took only a minute to prove that you were right! Loading it after my list items and script worked!

Comment: That's why jQuery is supposed to be wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){...});` :-P

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem - you make a very valid point, I'm sure. So sure, in fact, that, even though Gang Tian's answer worked, I removed the code at the bottom of my file and wrapped my script in the $(document).ready, but it did not work... suggestions?
                                    `

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          
$('.addtowishlist_<?php echo $apid; ?>').click(function(){
           $.get("wishlist/wishlistupdate.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>&apid=<?php echo $apid; ?>");
              $("#wishlistapps").load("wishlist/wishlistdisplay.php?uid=<?php echo $uid; ?>");
               
            
            $("li.app_<?php echo $apid; ?>").addClass("appwished");
            
            
            return false;
           });
          });
          
          
          </script>
                                    `

Comment: Well, on first glance I'd say you left out the `$('ul.version li:even').css()` bits...

Comment: ':odd' and ':even' are deprecated now. 

Use .odd() and .even() - https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/